# Populating template PDF using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying to fill out template PDF with data from excel worksheet using VBA and here's what I have so far;

```
FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE = "path_to\template.pdf"

Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")
Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If avDoc.Open(FILENAME, "") Then

    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    'populating pdf fields here, no issues

    FILE_NAME_RESULT = "path_to\result.pdf"
    pdDoc.Save PDSaveFull, FILE_NAME_RESULT

    pdDoc.Close

End If

avDoc.Close (True)
```

As is, code populates and saves `template.pdf`, however I'd like to leave template file unchanged and create the new `result.pdf` with populated data.  Please explain what am I doing wrong and thank you for your time.

Comment: `avDoc.Close (True)` - is this overwriting your template file? I'm not familiar with these libraries - why is that set to `True`?

Comment: @dwirony I'm not fluent in VBA at all, but I believe it should close the file without saving it https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf

Comment: The parameter is expecting a long, is `True` returning a positive number in this case? Try making that `(1)`.

Comment: @dwirony still makes changes to and saves `FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE` instead of `FILE_NAME_RESULT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Not enough points to just comment yet, so posting as an answer instead)*

Is `pdDoc.Close` a Function and if so, what's its return value?

As a workaround, you could copy the template to the result file first and then work on the file.

```
FileCopy FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE, FILE_NAME_RESULT
```

Let me add a coding style best practice recommendation: use all upper-case names for constants only. For actual variables, use mixed case names (like you did with e.g. pdDoc.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but if I `FileCopy` and fill out the new file - should work.  Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this too and it took me days: Just use the document flag (long) instead of the argument:

`pdDoc.Save 1, FILE_NAME_RESULT`